# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\exp\left[-\frac{a^2}{x}\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am interested in the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\exp\left[-\frac{a^2}{x}\right]$$

Does this limit exist for real $a$?

Edit: I am only interested in the case when $x$ is non-negative. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$, sure: introduce $u=1/x$, then you have

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} u^{1/2} e^{-a^2 u}$$

which is $0$ (for instance use L'Hopital's rule to prove it).

If you mean what you wrote, think about $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks. I am only interested in $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some use of the theory of distributions.

First of all, let's substitute $x \to y^2$ so you have

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\ \frac{1}{y}e^{-a^2/y^2}$$

Considering that $y$ goes to zero, I avoided to write $|y|$.

Now, there is a **Theorem** which states that if a function $u(x) \in L^1$ and if $u_{\lambda}(x) = \lambda u(\lambda x)$ then

$$\lim_{\lambda\to +\infty} u_{\lambda}(x) = C\delta(x)$$

where $\delta(x)$ is Dirac Delta Function and $C = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\ u(x)\ dx$

This works in our case: $$\frac{1}{y}e^{-a^2/y^2} = u_{\lambda}(a) = \lambda u(\lambda a)$$ where $$\lambda = \frac{1}{y}$$ and $$u(a) = e^{-a^2}$$

Thus, having the well known integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\ e^{-a^2}\ da = \sqrt{\pi} = C$$
we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-a^2/x} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1}{y}e^{-a^2/y^2} = \lim_{\lambda\to +\infty} \lambda u(\lambda a) = C\delta(a) = \sqrt{\pi}\delta(a)$$

Comment: Which theorem, and what is $\lambda$? Does the theorem allow $\lambda$ to be the argument of $u$?

Comment: @GyroGearloose The Dirac delta function can come out as the limit (in the sense of distributions) of the sequence of zero-centered normal distributions. Related article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

$\lambda$ is just a parameter which, as I wrote, is nothing but $1/y$. It's useful to explain the concept.

Comment: I still have a bad feeling about this. Do you have a direct link to the theorem?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Everyone who attended an advanced Calculus Course studied that theorem. At the moment I don't remember if it has a name or if it has not. But it's bloody sure that that theorem is a solid and well known one.

Comment: I didn't. So put it another way: can you give a reason why the other answers get a different result? Can you spot any error(s)?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Ok then I will search for the theorem, just wait. I have to check my old notes! Anyway, I don't know why other solutions are different from mine. Maybe they are wrong. I don't see any bad error in my solution..

Comment: Don't know about *your* "old notes", but mine fill about a cubic meter (with *no* index). No hurry, take your time.

Comment: Ouch, my fault, I understand now. Your function $u_\lambda(\lambda x)$ has $a=x$ (obvious as you stated it, but in my mind I associated $x$ with the variable and $\lambda$ with the parameter. So your solution gives $\lim\dots=0$ for $a\neq0$.

Comment: @ Kim Peek, although I see the my mistake leading to the above comments, I (and probably more readers) would like to have a link to the theorem you used. After all, one reason for this site is that we all should learn from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens when $x$ is negative?

Answer (score 0):

The left hand limit is not defined because of the square root in the denominator. So, you just need to check the value of the function at $f(0^+)$ and $f(0)$. If these two are equal, then limit is defined at $x=0$.